# Recovering from an old Wallet

Tags: wallet, wallet.dat

I have recovered my wallet from an old data file using Bitcoin Core. The wallet has synchronized without issues. I have tried to send BTC to at least two exchanges and neither transaction has completed. After the first transaction (going to the Coinbase Wallet) I waited 10 days and then tried increasing the transaction fee - no change. The returned stats code says "Status: 0/unconfirmed, not in memory pool, abandoned."

I then cancelled that send and tried sending to Kraken and it's still processing after six days. The status code for this one says "Status: 0/unconfirmed, not in memory pool?

Any ideas? Am I just SOL?

Answer (score -1):

As a workaround for the problem that you are facing - instead of using Bitcoin Core to send BTC to your account with the exchange, you might want to try exporting your wallet's private key from Bitcoin Core, then importing the private key to your account at the exchange.  See https://wallet.coinbase.com/faq/ (under 'Can I switch from my existing wallet app like Metamask, MyEtherWallet, etc.?') for information on how this is done with Coinbase.  Then, your BTC will be available in your account at the exchange.